# Running inference on InceptionV3 network twice bring totally different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

When i calculate inception score, i got NaN most of the time.

Trying to investigate why it happen i found that running the network twice on the same images can lead for some of the images to totally different results (difference greater than 0.9 while the maximum difference can be 1), the images which got high difference changed from run to run.

My GPU is 2080ti, i use Ubuntu with tensorflow=1.13.1.
i try to change drivers, tensorflow version, run form docker, the same problem happen all the time.

I have another server at the university which has the same GPU (2080ti), and when i try to run there the problem disappear.

Thanks for the help.

my script

```
# Code derived from tensorflow/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
import tarfile

import numpy as np
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import warnings
from scipy import linalg

MODEL_DIR = '/tmp/imagenet'
DATA_URL = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz'
softmax = None
pool3 = None

# Call this function with list of images. Each of elements should be a
# numpy array with values ranging from 0 to 255.
def get_features(images):
   assert ((images.shape[3]) == 3)
   assert (np.max(images) > 10)
   assert (np.min(images) >= 0.0)
   images = images.astype(np.float32)
   bs = 100
   sess = tf.get_default_session()
   preds = []
   for inp in np.array_split(images, round(images.shape[0] / bs)):
       sys.stdout.write(".")
       sys.stdout.flush()
       pred = sess.run(softmax, {'InputTensor:0': inp})
       preds.append(pred)
   preds = np.concatenate(preds, 0)
   return preds




# This function is called automatically.
def _init_inception():
   global softmax
   global pool3
   if not os.path.exists(MODEL_DIR):
       os.makedirs(MODEL_DIR)
   filename = DATA_URL.split('/')[-1]
   filepath = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, filename)
   if not os.path.exists(filepath):
       def _progress(count, block_size, total_size):
           sys.stdout.write('\r>> Downloading %s %.1f%%' % (
               filename, float(count * block_size) / float(total_size) * 100.0))
           sys.stdout.flush()

       filepath, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(DATA_URL, filepath, _progress)
       print()
       statinfo = os.stat(filepath)
       print('Succesfully downloaded', filename, statinfo.st_size, 'bytes.')
   tarfile.open(filepath, 'r:gz').extractall(MODEL_DIR)
   with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(
           MODEL_DIR, 'classify_image_graph_def.pb'), 'rb') as f:
       graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
       graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
       # Import model with a modification in the input tensor to accept arbitrary
       # batch size.
       input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 3],
                                     name='InputTensor')
       _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='inception_v3',
                               input_map={'ExpandDims:0': input_tensor})
   # Works with an arbitrary minibatch size.
   pool3 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('inception_v3/pool_3:0')
   ops = pool3.graph.get_operations()
   for op_idx, op in enumerate(ops):
       if 'inception_v3' in op.name:
           for o in op.outputs:
               shape = o.get_shape()
               shape = [s.value for s in shape]
               new_shape = []
               for j, s in enumerate(shape):
                   if s == 1 and j == 0:
                       new_shape.append(None)
                   else:
                       new_shape.append(s)
               o.set_shape(tf.TensorShape(new_shape))
   w = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("inception_v3/softmax/logits/MatMul").inputs[1]
   logits = tf.matmul(tf.squeeze(pool3, [1, 2]), w)
   softmax = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

_init_inception()
if __name__ =='__main__':
   (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       preds1 = get_features(x_train)
       preds2 = get_features(x_train)
       print(abs(preds1-preds2).max())
```